# How to write simple Hello World program in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and would like to start with very simple programs before moving forward to more advanced usage.

What would be most simple runnable AngularJS program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of most simple AngularJS program would be following.

```
<div ng-app>

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1>Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>

</div>
```

Here is how the output will look like:

---

[image: angularjs hello world]

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/vFcZ7/

**Reference:** http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-introduction-hello-world-tutorial/

Comment: wait...you asked a question and just answered it a few seconds later...why?

Comment: This is a very easy question, and I have one solution. I would welcome if others can post similar AngularJS related hello world programs showing how it works at basic level.

Comment: OK...I see. You're just documenting this for others to find.

Comment: Yes, documenting for others and myself.

Comment: But it is not the right answer. There are much simpler Angular programs !